Changing authentication in webforms asp.net from MySql 5.7 to 8.0
I need to upgrade our RDS MySql instance from 5.7 to 8.3. Can I continue to use the legacy authentication method I was using? I have run:
ALTER USER 'myuser' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';
flush privileges;
But cannot connect. The error I receive is:

